# Need to join tables in Tableau

Tags: csv, tableau-api, data-analysis

I have two csv files with the following Columns:

File1: CampaignId, Cost, CurrencyCode

File2: CurrencyCode, Conversion Factor to USD

So basically for every given currency code in File 1, I want to add the conversion factor from File 2 beside it so that I can convert the cost given in the Cost column in file 1 to USD for further analysis.

I tried using a Join in Tableau for this but it returns Null values even though I related the Currency Code of both tables when joining.

I want to get this done in Tableau alone (as file1 has about 50 million rows), so if anyone can help out here it'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Currency Codes - if they are identical they will join. You could also blend the data sources - but the same issues around forming the relationship exists.

You may need to TRIM and also set to UPPER (to remove any case issues) on one or both sides of the join / blend.

Comment: You are right. There were double quotes in currency codes of one of the files which didn't show up when I loaded it on Tableau and hence didn't notice that. Thanks!